# how to avoid highlighting all text over absolute positioned cousin div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, text

I have a problem with text-highlighting,

There is a div cover absolute positioned on top of a paragraph. In the DOM structure they are cousins.

When highlighting the paragraph text underneath, once the cursor hovers over the cover, the entire paragraph gets highlighted automatically, how to stop this?

[image: text selection before the cover:]

[image: mouse enters the cover all text gets selected]

JS fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/toplay3/c741LoLv/

```
#cover{
  position:absolute;
  top:10px;
  left:50px;
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  background-color:green;
  /*-webkit-user-select: none;*/
}
```

For some reason google slides is able to avoid this with svg,anyway to do it in html?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
pointer-events: none;
```

on the `#cover` element

https://jsfiddle.net/c741LoLv/2/

This removes normal pointer functionality from the element - highlight, hover, focus etc.

> The CSS property pointer-events allows authors to control under what circumstances (if any) a particular graphic element can become the target of mouse events.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/pointer-events/